# R: Drawing multiple polygons with different alphas automatically

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

assume I've this short reproducible example:

```
d=data.frame(x=c(1,2,2, 3,4,4), y=c(1,1,2, 2,2,3), t=c('a', 'a', 'a',  'b', 'b', 'b'))
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=d, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, group=t)) 

p
```

that produces two triangles. However I'll have a data.frames containing more of those. I want to plot them automatically with an decreasing "Alpha" argument. Would there be a way to do this in a loop (I wouldnt also need the group argument), or would it be smarter somehow to define the alpha values inside the data.frame ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would define an `alpha` column in `d` and then map that to the `alpha` aesthetic inside `aes`.

For example:

```
d <- data.frame(
    x = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4),
    y = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3),
    t = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
    alpha = rep(1:2, each = 3))

ggplot(d, aes(x, y, group = t, alpha = alpha)) +
  geom_polygon() +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.4, 0.8), guide = F)
```

[image]

The ordering of `d$alpha` determines the shading, the range of which you can set with `scale_alpha_continuous`. In this case, the polygon with the lowest `alpha` has `alpha = 0.4` and the polygon with the highest `alpha` has `alpha = 0.8`.

---

### Update

As pointed out by @Axeman you can also consider using `scale_alpha_identity` which requires directly "translatable" `alpha` values in `d`

```
d <- data.frame(
    x = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4),
    y = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3),
    t = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
    alpha = rep(c(0.1, 0.9), each = 3))

ggplot(d, aes(x, y, group = t, alpha = alpha)) +
  geom_polygon() +
  scale_alpha_identity()
```

Here, the first polygon has `alpha = 0.1` and the second one `alpha = 0.9`. Note that this requires you to pre-compute `alpha` values for all polygons.

[image]

Comment: That helps, thank you. In the case where I've more then two triangles and where I want to supply my "own" alpha sequence, how can I do it. A simple range=c(0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8) doesnt work

Comment: @rook1996 You just need to give the polygons an ordered number in your `data.frame`. The rest stays the same. `range = c(0.4, 0.8)` defines the min/max of the `alpha` values. If you have 2, one polygon has 0.4 the other 0.8. If you have 3 polygons, their `alpha`s will automatically be 0.4, 0.6, 0.8. And so on.

Comment: Remember, there is `scale_alpha_identity` if you want to map directly to your own alpha sequence. (But probably you just want to map automatically like shown here.)

Comment: @rook1996 Example added.